# UWP Tile not showing svg image

Tags: .net-core, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, msix

Following code for a Tile on windows 10 start menu shows a '.png' image that I created using [MS Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint). But the same code does not show a similar `.svg` image (in the Tile) that I created using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/).

**Question**: Why the same code does not work for `.svg` image while it works for `.png` image - and how can we make it work for `.svg` images, as well?

**Snapshot of Start menu with a Tile display with .png file**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
public void TileTest()
{
    // Construct the tile content
    TileContent content = new TileContent()
    {
        Visual = new TileVisual()
        {
            TileWide = new TileBinding()
            {

                Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveGroup()
                        {
                            Children =
                            {
                                new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                {
                                    HintWeight = 2,
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveImage()
                                        {
                                           //NOTE: if I replace Test.png with Test.svg image, it 
                                            //does not show up
                                            Source = "Images/MyImages/Test.png",
                                            HintRemoveMargin = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(content.GetXml());
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
}
```

**Remark**:  It may not matter, but just in case: I'm using a [Packaged WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) that is calling UWP/WinRT APIs - using `VS2019 - ver 16.9` and `.NET5` on `Windows 10 Pro - ver 2004`.
Following are the `.png` and `.svg` Images I tried on the above code. .svg did not show up in the tile:

**Test.png**:

[image]

**Test.Svg**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <rect
       x="60.47619"
       y="99.785714"
       width="74.839286"
       height="34.017857"
       id="rect24" />
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="400"
     inkscape:cy="560"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1267"
     inkscape:window-height="728"
     inkscape:window-x="83"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="text22"
       style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10.5833px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Bookman Old Style';-inkscape-font-specification:'Bookman Old Style Bold';text-align:center;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect24)"
       x="0"
       y="0"><tspan
         x="85.936012"
         y="109.17887"><tspan
           style="text-align:center;text-anchor:middle">Test</tspan></tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: we often use UWP app icon generator to make app's visual assets, when you select a image you will find svg type not in the support list.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have another question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67426219/1232087) if you have any solution/suggestions etc. - Thank you.