# UWP Tiles - AdaptiveImage AlternateText not showing up

Tags: .net-core, uwp, .net-5, windows-community-toolkit, msix

**Question**: Why my following code for a Tile on windows 10 start menu shows the image, but when I hover over the image it does not show the [Alternate Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.adaptiveimage.alternatetext?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable). What I may be missing here, and how can we make it work?

**Code**:

```
public void TileTest()
{
    TileContent content = new TileContent()
    {
        Visual = new TileVisual()
        {
            TileWide = new TileBinding()
            {

                Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveGroup()
                        {
                            Children =
                            {
                                new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                {
                                    HintWeight = 2,
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveImage()
                                        {
                                            Source = "Images/MyImages/Test.png",
                                            AlternateText = "Test alternative text"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(content.GetXml());
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
}
```

**Remark**: It may not matter, but just in case: I'm using a [Packaged WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) that is calling UWP/WinRT APIs - using `VS2019 - ver 16.9` and `.NET5` on `Windows 10 Pro - ver 2004`.

Comment: Does it work when you use the independent wpf app to implement? In addition, I suggest that you could create a separate uwp app to check whether it works.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT This is happening in `UWP`, as well.

Comment: You could read the official document about [Create adaptive tiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/create-adaptive-tiles) to check your code.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Actually I used the section [Groups and subgroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/create-adaptive-tiles#groups-and-subgroups) from the  link `Create adaptive tiles`  you referenced above. But none of the code examples there use `AlternateText`

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the meaning of the AlternateText, there is no related information indicate AlternateText can show image information when you hover over the image.